# Understanding the empty set subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to understand the concept that the empty set is a subset of all sets, including itself. However, what I'm not sure about is whether it means, for example:

$p = ∅$, $p$ a subset of $∅$

or does it mean

$p = \{∅\}$, $p$ is a subset of $∅$

Comment: Your first interpretation is correct. $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set, since there is no element in $\emptyset$ to proof the condition in the first place.

Comment: Use the def of *subset*: $A \subseteq B \text { iff } x \in A \to x \in B, \text { for every } x$.

Comment: $\emptyset \subseteq B$ because $x \in \emptyset \to x \in B, \text { for every } x$ holds [vacuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). And this is true for every $B$.

Answer (score 0):

For all sets A, it is the case that $\varnothing\subseteq A$. The second statement you wrote is incorrect since $\varnothing\in p$ but $\varnothing\notin\varnothing$.

Comment: so in the second statement because p contains the element ∅ (p={∅}) rather than it being defined as an empty set (p=∅), then it is not the same?

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with two different objects.

$\varnothing$ is the empty set; it has 0 elements;

$\{\varnothing\}$ is the set containing the empty set as sole element; it has 1 elements.

Now,

$\varnothing\subseteq\varnothing$

is TRUE, because the empty set is a subset of every other set (or also because any set is a subset of itself).

$\{\varnothing\}\subseteq\varnothing$

is clearly FALSE, since the first set contains 1 element and the second set contains 0 elements.